# Is shrinking and deallocating space necessary after Advanced Table Compression?

Tags: oracle, compression

There is a table that holds 10 GB of data without any compress assigned to it. A decision was made to use advanced compresion on this table to reduce amount of space it consumed.
After running the below command :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MOVE ONLINE ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED 
                      UPDATE INDEXES PARALLEL 5 NOLOGGING  ;
```

space it used was reduced to 5.6 GB.
Is this the final point of efficient usage of space?

Or should I run `alter table shrink space` and `deallocate space` too on this table after compression is done? Couldn't find enough information on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "MOVE" is a full reorganisation of the table, so all blocks are completely rewritten, and any space freed up is released back to the tablespace(s) that contain the table.

No further reclamation steps are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! One other problem we are facing with this is huge archive log generation during compress, since it moves partitions. I think i should remove update indexes statement from the command and then manually rebuild them

Comment: Doing the indexes separately will definitely help because UPDATE INDEXES is effectively the same as doing the index maintenance in "conventional" style, ie a delete-insert